# Nativescript - Keep keyboard open when TextField returned on Android

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can I keep the keyboard open after the user tap on the "Return" key on the soft keyboard?
I'm calling the focus method on "returnPress" event, which works fine on IOS but not on android:

```
text() {
    let textFieldElement = <TextField>this.textField.nativeElement;
    textFieldElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: The android method for an EditText view (the native underlying element) is `requestFocus`.

Comment: @pkanev I dont think this would work... AFAIK I should handle the returnPress event but not sure how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out I need to overrde "onEditorAction" method on the "OnEditorActionListener" like this:

```
    let tv = <TextField>this.textField.nativeElement;

    if (tv.android) {
        tv.android.setOnEditorActionListener(new android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener({
            onEditorAction: function (callbackType, result) {
                if (result == android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        // do whatever you want when user presses return
                }
                return true;
            }
        }));
    }
```